# Javascript: Extract part of URL, clean it, and use it within html embed code for a flash container

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, embed, ecmascript-5

*Sorry in advance, lots of answers on this site relate to parts of this query, though I am failing to connect the dots. Any help will be appreciated (happy to buy virtual beers, etc)*

I'm looking to take a URL, and extract part of the string to the left of "&folderCTID", and the right of "RootFolder=", e.g:

This:
*http://mysite.com/Project1/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FProject1%2FLesson%2014&FolderCTID=0x01200075C0E8AC5A64724787732A3200049D3A&View={440F5454-054D-4C68-A1E2-4A52E4FD8FCB}*

Becomes:
*%2FProject1%2FLesson%2014*

I am then looking to replace the "%2F" with "/", and add a trailing "/presentation.swf", leaving me with my **file reference** - "/Project1/Lesson%2014/presentation.swf"

Finally, I'd like to use the file reference within an  embed code, e.g. src=&quot/Project1/Lesson%2014/presentation.swf&quot

Is this even possibe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
theURL='http://mysite.com/Project1/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FProject1%2FLesson%2014&FolderCTID=0x01200075C0E8AC5A64724787732A3200049D3A&View={440F5454-054D-4C68-A1E2-4A52E4FD8FCB}';

filePath = theURL.match(/RootFolder\=(.*?)&/)[1].replace(/%2F/g, "/")+"/presentation.swf";

alert(filePath);
```

I don't think you even need to decode the url to use it in the src so you could just use

```
filePath = theURL.match(/RootFolder\=(.*?)&/)[1]+"%2Fpresentation.swf";
```

Try SWFObject https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>SWFObject dynamic embed - step 3</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF(filePath, "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myContent">
      <p>Alternative content</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

or if you are using jQuery you can try http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').flash(
        { src: filePath,
          width: 720,
          height: 480 },
        { version: 8 }
    );
});

<div id="example">You don't have flash</div>
```

or http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#myFlash').flash(filePath);
    }
);

<div id="myFlash">You don't have flash</div>
```

I have included the filePath variable in the right place in the above examples

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that works a treat. If i wanted to add that variable (filePath) inside HTML code, e.g. <object><embed> src=***variable here*** </embed></object> - how would I do it?

Comment: Amazing Daniel - thanks for this - Please pick your online favour redemption tool (amazon wishlist, etc).

Comment: Thanks Tom very generous, if you have an problems setting up give me a shout at the mail address i have you

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Yes**

```
var url = "http://mysite.com/Project1/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FProject1%2FLesson%2014&FolderCTID=0x01200075C0E8AC5A64724787732A3200049D3A&View={440F5454-054D-4C68-A1E2-4A52E4FD8FCB}",
i = 0, len, part;

url = url.split("?").pop().split("&");
len = url.length;

for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
    part = url[i].split("=");
    if ( part[0] === "RootFolder" ) {
        break;
    }
}

part = decodeURIComponent(part[1]);

console.log(part); // "/Project1/Lesson 14"
```

Comment: Thanks Null, your solution works perfectly at extracting the file URL!

Comment: P.s. I have found another great use for this code - as per Daniel please pick your online favour redemption tool (amazon wishlist, etc)

Comment: You should not encourage payment for stackoverflow answering. Here we use rep for this. You can make a bounty and reward daniel with some of your rep. Or upvote if an answer is good. And accept an answer also reward the user answered it rep.

Comment: If you have something to say to a specific user / answer. Please make a comment on that answer and use the `@user` if multiply users is commenting the post.